# Ocultar texto si sobrepasa div responsivo

Tags: html, css, css3, responsive

Tengo un div con un texto algo largo, pero como es muy largo tiende a saltar a la siguiente linea, y lo que necesito es que se quede sobre la misma linea y si el texto es muy largo que solo llegue hasta el tope del div y lo demás se oculte:

Tengo lo siguiente, como pueden ver se sobrepasa de mi div el text:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realice unos ajustes y logre adaptarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mi siguiente problema es que al hacerlo responsivo a menos de 500px de ancho se queda como con el mismo ancho y no se adapta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea, para lograr hacerlo responsivo, este es mi css para el div:

```
.selected {
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.s-box{
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: var(--black);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2.2rem;
}

<!-- Mi HTML -->
<div class="w-100 s-box">
  <div class="selected">
    Servicios inmobiliarios .....
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un [repro] en la pregunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulto me base de esta respuesta donde ocurria algo similar:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642505/white-space-nowrap-css-style-not-allowing-for-table-to-be-responsive

Al momento de definir mi white-space: nowrap, el ancho se queda en linea y de manera fija, que afecto en mi responsivo en pantallas menores de 500px, agregue un min-width del 100% y un width de 50px y funciono excelente